# Trouble applying function with multiple optional arguments

Tags: r, return-value, apply

I would like the function 'count' to count the number of entries in 'data' that meet 'critvalue' by the 'operator' = 1 (<), =2 (=), = 3 (>).

```
count = function(data,critvalue,operator=2) { 
    if (operator == 1){
        sum(data < critvalue)}
    if (operator == 2){ 
        sum(data == critvalue)}
    if (operator == 3){
        sum(data > critvalue)}}
```

It works on a vector of values:

```
count(rep(6,10),critvalue=5,operator=1)
```

When I apply this function to a matrix to count by row, it doesn't work:

```
m = rbind(1:10,1:10,1:10)
apply(m, 1, count, critvalue = 6)
```

But when I define the function 'count' to not take the operator argument, it somehow works

```
count = function(data,critvalue,operator=2) {
     sum(data == critvalue)}

apply(m, 1, count, critvalue = 6)
```

Any help in figuring out why this doesn't work in the apply function would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I would definitely be interested in base functions that already count like this.  I tried 'sum', but don't know how to use it in apply.

```
sum(m == 6)  #works

apply(m,1,sum,   #no idea how set the criteria for being equal to 6
```

Comment: Your first problem is that `m` is not a matrix. Read `?matrix` and `?c`.

Comment: oops, yeah, I noticed that and meant to change it to rbind...just edited the post to reflect that, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would use `switch`:

```
m <- matrix(c(1:10,1:10,1:10),ncol=3)

count <- function(data,critvalue,operator=2) { 
  switch(operator,
         sum(data < critvalue),
         sum(data == critvalue),
         sum(data > critvalue))
}

apply(m, 1, count, critvalue = 6)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0

apply(m, 1, count, critvalue = 6, operator = 3)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3
```

---

## Edit: Why your function does not work.

From `?return`:

> If the end of a function is reached without calling return, the value
>   of the last evaluated expression is returned.

The last expression of your function is `if (operator == 3){
        sum(data > critvalue)}`.

From `?if`:

> if returns the value of the expression evaluated, or NULL invisibly if
>   none was (which may happen if there is no else).

So, in case `operator` != 3 your function returns `NULL`:

```
apply(m, 1, count, critvalue = 6)
#NULL
```

You fix that by using `return`:

```
count <- function(data,critvalue,operator=2) { 
  if (operator == 1){
    return(sum(data < critvalue))}
  if (operator == 2){ 
    return(sum(data == critvalue))}
  if (operator == 3){
    return(sum(data > critvalue))}}    

apply(m, 1, count, critvalue = 6)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0
```

However, `switch` is more convenient here.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly!  Do you know why I couldn't use the if statements?  I'm just wondering if it will help me understand the apply function better.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Added an explanation. The problem is not related to `apply`.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to explain.  However, I'm not sure I completely understand.  According to your explanation, the last if statement is causing the problem; since the if statements have no return, the end of the function is reached and returns the last evaluate expression: if (operator == 3){...}.  However, the function works when data is a vector and the apply function is not used (see second code block in post).  If the problem is the lack of returns, why does the function still work on the vector supplied above?

Comment: Really? I just tried the first two blocks of code, and got no output when i executed count on the vector.

Comment: @jhjudd On my systems (R 3.0.1 Mac OS X, R 3.0.0 Win7) your functions returns `NULL` if passed a vector and `operator`!=3.